# How to find where an Alert is initiated in Oracle Forms 6i?

Tags: oracle, alert, oracleforms

in a Oracle 6i form, I have an alert defined, and a database block. Because it's a database block, when some data is entered, but not saved, when you try to exit this form, this alert pops up (asking 'Do you want to save this data?'). However, all this happens BY DEFAULT, I don't see any triggers/program units where this alert is called... Also, the text for this alert is also assigned dynamically, and I can't find any triggers/programs where it is being done... What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can *find it* anywhere in Forms Builder; that behavior is **built-in**, Oracle Forms raises the alert when it finds out that one (or more) database items have been changed, and those changes not saved at the moment you're trying to e.g. exit the form, enter query mode, navigate to another record etc.

In order to prevent changes to be lost (end users would *hate it*, spending minutes to enter data which is *gone* without notice), Forms informs you about it and lets you choose whether you want to keep (save) those changes or not.

Therefore, just say "Thank you" every time you see it because those nice people at Oracle did it so that us, developers, wouldn't have to in each and every form we create.